# Canon 70D Live View stops after some time

Tags: canon, live-view, canon-70d, magic-lantern

I'm trying to set my Canon 70D up in a way where the live view stays active, but I can 't seem to get it right, even with ML installed.

I've already set the power settings to never auto turn off, but after about 20 minutes or so, it still turns off live view (in both video and picture mode) and shows a screen that just says "Press (Start/Stop) button to activate movie shooting).

Is there any way to make it not do this and just stay in live view until I turn it off myself?

Answer (score 2):

So I kind of have a solution?

Basically, with ML, you can set a setting called "Sticky half-shutter", where you press it right when you enable live view and it simulates the half shutter being held down.

Sadly on the 70D, this version of ML doesn't have that option. So I went ahead and rubber banded a small nut over the shutter button, which keeps it perfectly at half shutter.

So yup! Now I stream on Twitch with my 70D.